# How to open a view controller on table row click in xamarin ios without using segue concept

Tags: ios, xamarin

How to open a view controller on table row click in xamarin ios without using segue concept ?????

Comment: This is a very good information, but where is the question? Things you have tried, etc, etc?

Comment: Hi, My question is 

How to open a view controller on table row click in xamarin ios without using segue concept ?????

Answer (score 0):

You can use `present(viewController, animated: true) {}` this method to present a view controller, and if you have a navigation controller you can use `navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)`

Answer (score 0):

In your UITableViewSource override the method "RowSelected" as Follows:

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    //Instantialte the Storyboard Object
    UIStoryboard storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("YourStoryboardName", null);

    //Instantiate the ViewController you want to navigate to.
    //Make sure you have set the Storyboard ID for this ViewController in your storyboard file.
    //Put this Storyboard ID in place of the TargetViewControllerName in below line. 
    UIViewController vcInstance = (UIViewController)storyboard.InstantiateViewController ("TargetViewControllerName");


    //Get the Instance of the TopViewController (CurrentViewController) or the NavigationViewController to push the TargetViewController onto the stack. 
    //NavigationController is an Instance of the NavigationViewController
    NavigationController.PushViewController(vcInstance, true);
}
```

Or

Using the Event Mechanism, Register this event in the ViewController for the MyTableSource object, where your TableView is added.

```
public class MyTableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    public event EventHandler<RowSelectedEventArgs> OnRowSelected;

    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (OnRowSelected != null) {
            OnRowSelected (this, new RowSelectedEventArgs (tableView, indexPath));
    }
}


public class MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    MyTableSourceObject.OnRowSelected += (s, ev) => {
        //Your Navigation Logic Goes Here.
    }
}
```

Comment: I am binding table data in separate cs file not inside view controller.Getting this error

Comment: Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Could not find a storyboard named 'StoryboardMain' in bundle NSBundle </Users/ratneshkumar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AACF7EC5-40CF-4A3F-A95E-5723EF1FCAAB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BFDEDFDE-4CAB-482E-B9C9-DC9D85C712B2/BizSolMobileApp.app> (loaded)
Native stack trace:
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001134e4b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001140a7141

Comment: Please make sure you have given a correct Storyboard Name. Ex. Storyboard file name is Main.storyboard then storyboard name should be "Main"

Comment: My Problem is not solved yet using above code I did not get any error but another controller not displaying.

Comment: It would be great if you can share some code for the navigation and row click event. Also let me see your target view controller property from storyboard.